# First tab shows for a moment while staying on the current tab after page refresh in bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

After page refresh, first tab shows for a moment and then stays on the current tab. How can I avoid showing the first tab?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if(activeTab){
    $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
});
</script>

<div class="bs-example">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#brandName">Brand Name</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#generic">Generic</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#itemType">Item Type</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#category">Category</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#items">Items</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

    <div id="brandName" class="tab-pane fade in active">
```

Please find the relevant code added here.

Edited code (for select first tab as the default tab, when page loads for the first time, after closing the tab or debugging):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if(activeTab){
    $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
else{ $('#myTab a').first().tab('show'); }
});
```

Edit 2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
});
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
if(activeTab){
    $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
}
else{ $('#myTab a:first').tab('show'); }
});
```

Comment: remove `.active` class from `li` and `.in` `.active` classes from `.tab-pane`

Comment: @tmg Thanks friend, it works. But now how can I set the first tab as the default tab, without having the previous issue? 
And, appreciate if you could please help me to understand the java-script code line by line, since I am a newbie to programming.

Comment: You check if 'activeTag', add the else case: `if(activeTab){...}else{ $('#myTab a').first().tab('show'); }`

Comment: @tmg it seems to be not working. I have added the edited code as your comment, above. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: try $('#myTab a:first').tab('show') instead

Comment: @tmg still not working friend. It still remains on the last selected tab even though I close the browser tab and re-debug. I have added the updated code under "Edit 2"